# Reuse a connection object in fabric

Tags: python, fabric

Using fabric is it possible that i could create a connection object to a bastion server and use that object to interact with the VMs behind the bastion ?

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean that your server resides behind a proxy server?

Comment: Yes, bastion is a proxy server in between.

Answer (score 0):

Used ParallelSSH to solve this.

```
from pssh.clients import ParallelSSHClient
from pssh.utils import load_private_key

PRIVATE_KEY = "pvt.key"
USER = "username"
BASTION = "proxy_host"

hosts = ["h1", "h2"]
client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts, user=USER,
                           proxy_host=BASTION, proxy_user=USER,
                           proxy_port=2222,
                           proxy_pkey=load_private_key(PRIVATE_KEY))

out = client.run_command("ls -la")


for host in hosts:
    print(host+"\n********************\n")

    for line in out[host].stdout:
        print(line)
```